# How can create a view to filter the a list based on the current login user

Tags: listview, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

How to create a view based on the current user is in a Person or Group field , this Person or Group field can contain multiple user but not SharePoint Group ,I try to use the contains to filter the data but getting the following error:

[image]

Can someone shine some light on how to create  a filter based on Person or Group? E.G. , I have a Person or Group field called StakeHolders(can contain more than one user) for the current project , How can create  a view to filter the project based on the current login user.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is possible an easy way. Would be interested to know if it's possible. Although, I have done something similar via using custom CAML and ListViewByQuery inside a site page.

Another similar solution [here](http://sharepointjavascript.wordpress.com/2010/02/16/filter-list-view-based-on-membership-in-sharepoint-group/)